# How Configure Azure with Grafana for CPU,DISK and MEMORY Usage?

Tags: linux, azure, grafana, redhat

I used a RedHat 8.1 Linux server in azure. So, I want to monitor CPU, Disk, and memory usage in grafana. What is the process for configuring Azure with grafana? Please, anyone, help me regarding this issue.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the process for configuring Azure with grafana?

You can integrate Azure with Grafana to monitor the CPU, DISK and MEMORY Usage.

Follow the steps as mentioned by @Peter De Tender in this [document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/monitoring-azure-by-using-grafana-dashboards/) to configure and monitor azure using grafana.

Comment: Thank you for your Reply @RajkumanMamidichettu-MT. I setup CPU usage but i didn't get DISK and MEMORY Usage How can I get those?